# Wait before the activity is fully displayed

Tags: android, android-activity

I'm currently having a problem when a button is pressed before the activity is fully displayed. My app is a questionnaire type that spawns buttons as options for the question. If I press the button repeatedly and fast, a black screen will randomly occur but the activity will still display afterwards.

My current solution is to put a delay before I set the event listener to the buttons.

```
private Runnable task = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
                addEventHandlerToButtons();
        }
    };
```

And put this in `onCreate` or `onPostCreate`

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(task, 500);
```

Comment: Is your solution working?

Comment: can you share your button onClick event?

Comment: There is clearly not enough code here to figure out what's going on.